# CodeIgniter object not found only the index function works

Tags: php, html, codeigniter

I am new to CodeIgniter, everything was going fine and well up until I found out that I can only make a call to the `index()` function.

I have setup the `config.php`, `autoload.php` and `routes.php` as expected.

on the config.php

```
$config['base_url'] = 'http://localhost/ci';
$config['index_page'] = '';
```

on the autoload.php

```
$autoload['helper'] = array('form','url');
```

on the routes.php

```
$route['default_controller'] = "site";
```

I have a controller named site

```
<?php

    class Site extends CI_Controller{

        function index(){
            $this->load->view('home');
        }

        function new_method(){
            $this->load->view('home2');
        }
    }
?>
```

I have to 2 files on the view folder with their HTML code, simply named home.php and 
home2.php

on home.php I have

```
<?php 
    echo form_open('site/new_method');
    echo form_submit('submit', 'call method'); 
    echo ('<br /><br />');
    echo anchor('site/new_method', 'call method');
    echo form_close();
?>
```

The index() loads, as results U get a button and a link but when I click I am given 
Object not found! Error 404

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. You can make this empty `$config['base_url'] = '';`
2. Check .htaccess in root folder with index.php file
3. Check mod_rewrite apache module is enabled

`RewriteEngine On
 RewriteBase /
 RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
 RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
 RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L]`

Comment: thanx i have went to apache and i still don't understand what is going on with the .htaccess. The problem was that i had gone and removerd the index.php on the congfig like this ($config['index_page'] = '';). all i had to do was to type in the index.php back like ($config['index_page'] = 'index.php';).

Answer (score 7):

Follow the steps that Furqan mentioned, but if that doesn't work, try this in your .htaccess file (in the root of your project):

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|assets|images|js|css|uploads|favicon.png)
RewriteCond %(REQUEST_FILENAME) !-f
RewriteCond %(REQUEST_FILENAME) !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ ./index.php/$1 [L]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Check the uri_protocol in the config file that should be AUTO.

Config/config.php ===> $config['uri_protocol']  = 'AUTO';
```

Answer (score 0):

create a .htaccess file inside your root directory and write the below code there.

```
DirectoryIndex index.php

Options -Indexes

RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?/$1 [L,QSA]
```

Answer (score -1):

I had that problem but It coused by moving project from window to linux, I solve this by writing the controller as it is. example ***http://localhost/AppController/blog*** instead of using ***http://localhost/appcontroller/blog***
thanks!

Comment: Answers added to this page must only answer the asker's specific question, not merely experience a similar problem (typo).

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/32442265)