# How to set dynamic route in codeigniter from database?

Tags: php, html, mysql, codeigniter

In my routes.php file I have added the following code for routing:

```
$route['report/:num'] = "home/reportcard/$1";
```

Here is my controller code:

```
<?php
    defined('BASEPATH') OR exit('No direct script access allowed');

    class Home extends CI_Controller
    {

        function __construct() {
            parent::__construct();

        if(empty($this->session->userdata('id_user'))){
            $this->session->set_flashdata('flash_data', 'You cannot access');
                    redirect('login');
        }
        }
        public function index(){
            $this->load->model("item_model");
            $data['records'] = $this->item_model->getAllItems();
            $this->load->view('home',$data);
        }

       function reportcard($id){
            $this->load->model("item_model");
            $data['report'] = $this->item_model->getReport($id);
            $this->load->view('report', $data);  
        }

        function logout(){
            $data=['id_user','username'];
            $this->session->unset_userdata($data);
            redirect('login');

        }
    }
```

Here is my model code:

```
<?php
    class Item_model extends CI_Model
    {
        function getAllItems()
        {
            $this->load->database();
            $q = $this->db->get("item");
            if($q->num_rows() > 0)
            {
                return $q->result();
            }
            return array();
        }

        public function getReport($id){
            $this->db->select('*');
            $this->db->from('item');
            $this->db->where('item.id', $id);  
            $query = $this->db->get();    
            if($query->num_rows() > 0)
                return $data->result();
        }

}
?>
```

this is the code of view. I just print the array in my report_view for testing purpose:

```
<?php
defined('BASEPATH') OR exit('No direct script access allowed');
print_r($report);
?>
```

this is my home_view code:

```
<div class="row">
                <ul class="home-grid">
                    <?php foreach ($query->result() as $row): ?>
                    <li>
                        <a  href="<?php echo base_url() ?>report/<?=$row->item ?>/<?=$row->id ?>" class="btn btn-lg btn-warning view-report"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-list-alt"></span> <br/>
                        <?=$row->item ?><br/>
                         <small>Click here for see report</small>
                        </a>
                    </li>
                    <?php endforeach; ?>
                </ul>
```

I have tried multiple times to view the array. But failed to get array. How can I load the view? When I click my items from home, it will create a url like http://localhost/super_shop_register/report/1

But didn't show any data. Show "Object not found!". Here is the image of my view: [image: Home View]
After Clicking item, it will show like this: [image: after clicking item]

How can I solve this?

Comment: Is super_shop_register part of your base_url? And in the view code you posted it looks like their should be two parameters after report/, $row->item and $row->id, why does only the id appear?

Comment: I think it matches with another route can you post your full route

Comment: base_url is ok. When I took a snapshot, the code was only $row-id. That's why showed only id in the url. It's not a big deal at all.

$config['base_url'] = 'http://localhost/super_shop_register';

Comment: Here is my route.php code:

$route['default_controller'] = 'login';
$route['report/:num'] = "home/reportcard/$1";
$route['404_override'] = '';
$route['translate_uri_dashes'] = FALSE;

Comment: I don't think the problem is in your codeigniter routing because that 404 wasn't generated by codeigniter but by your server. My guess is it is an .htaccess problem, but it's strange that it would only affect this one page.

Comment: I think I didn't connect the page properly. But didn't get the exact problem as I am new in CodeIgniter. I have tried many times. But couldn't find any solution.

Comment: is your file name of controller Home.php not home.php

Comment: file name is home.php

Comment: No one notice this why ?  
In your model this is wrong return $data->result(); actually $query->result(); is right.

Comment: Wolfgang is correct that is should be Home.php. Depending on your enviornment it may or may not fix your problem, but if your site ever gets places in a Linux server this will create major problems, always title your files in Codeigniter with Capitalized names. 

@Nobita - OP responded to your post. It's not relevant to the problem anyway.

Comment: I have tried both. home.php and Home.php
didn't work

Comment: Did you removed index.php from config and updated the .htaccess in your root?

Comment: Yeah. Now its working perfectly.

Answer (score 2):

change your root from `$route['report/:num'] = "home/reportcard/$1";`
to

```
$route['report/(:num)'] = "home/reportcard/$1";
```

and

```
<a  href="<?php echo base_url() ?>report/<?=$row->item ?>/<?=$row->id ?>" class="btn btn-lg btn-warning view-report">
```

this line of code will create `href="localhost/super_shop_register/report/Chips/1"`.
You need to remove `<?=$row->item ?>/` from it.

Comment: url is created like this. But still show "Object not found!

The requested URL was not found on this server. The link on the referring page seems to be wrong or outdated. Please inform the author of that page about the error. "

Comment: You changed the root like I suggested?

Comment: I have changed the route which you suggested.

Comment: `localhost/super_shop_register/index.php/report/1` . Then try opening this url. Note the last parameter should be a valid item ID instead of 1.

Comment: If I open this url, it will print the array with value which I want to print.
Output :  Hello WorldArray ( [0] => stdClass Object ( [id] => 3 [item] => Chocolate [description] => Chocolate [created] => 2017-03-07 ) )

Comment: Alright. Then there is nothing wrong with your code.
You need to change .htaccess file. Please visit this [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19183311/codeigniter-removing-index-php-from-url)

Comment: If you don't want to do this for now, then change
`$config['base_url'] = 'localhost/super_shop_register/index.php'`

Comment: But If I set this base_url, other pages are not showed.

Comment: It should be set in my particular page. Not in my config.php file.

Comment: You have to change you htaccess file or always have to use index.php in your URLs

Comment: Thanks @M Hussain

Answer (score 1):

In your model this is wrong `return $data->result();` actually `$query->result();` is right.

```
<?php
    class Item_model extends CI_Model
    {
        function getAllItems()
        {
            $this->load->database();
            $q = $this->db->get("item");
            if($q->num_rows() > 0)
            {
                return $q->result();
            }
            return array();
        }

        public function getReport($id){
            $this->db->select('*');
            $this->db->from('item');
            $this->db->where('item.id', $id);  
            $query = $this->db->get();    
            if($query->num_rows() > 0)
                return $data->result();
        }

}
?>
```

Comment: Opps. Mistake. Edited return $data->result(); to return $query->result();
Still not working.

Answer (score 1):

Come on man, your code works perfect in my workout example

my route

```
$route['report/(:num)'] = "welcome/workout/$1";
```

My Welcome controller

```
public function workout($id)
    {

        echo $id;

    }
```

my url is

```
http://localhost/Code/report/1
```

my output is

```
1
```

[image]

make sure you done the following

1. removed the index.php on the config like this ($config['index_page'] = '';).
2. Check .htaccess in root folder with index.php file

   and make it below

   RewriteEngine On

   RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f

   RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

   RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L]

Reference: [CodeIgniter object not found only the index function works](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16966290/codeigniter-object-not-found-only-the-index-function-works)

when i removed my .htaccess code, your error occurs

[image]

hope this helps :)

Comment: @Tanzila Can you check the url as, http://localhost/super_shop_register/index.php/report/1
comment your response.

Answer (score 0):

your route should be like this:

```
$route['report/(:num)'] = "home/reportcard/$1";
```

and make sure your htaccess file is there and have code:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule .* index.php?/$0 [PT,L]
```

Answer (score 0):

Simple you can try this

```
$route['report/(:num)'] = "home/reportcard";
```

**then you can get ID with below method in controller and nothing pass in function reportcard argument**

```
$report_id = $this->uri->segment(2);
```

Comment: The problem is with routing. Direct function parameter can achieve the data from the url.